# Universal Hashfunctions for string

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, hashtable

I am trying to implement two different universal hash functions for strings.
But I have the problem that sometimes the hash value is 0.
With this I can´t use the hash function because I want to implement double hashing and have to implement this function: hash_func1(string s) + i * hash_func2(string s) to go through the hash table.
But if one hash function is 0 nothing changes and I get an endless loop.
This is for collision detection in a hash table.
I need two different universal hash functions for doing that.

I have tried different hash functions but cant find anything that works.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

This are some of the functions I have tried.

```
int h = 0 , r1 = 31415 , r2 = 27183;
 for (int i =0; i < key.length (); i ++) {
 h = ( r1 * h + key.charAt ( i )) % capacity ;
 r1 = r1 * r2 % (capacity -1);
}
return h ;
```

Or this one

```
int seed = 131; 
long hash = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
{
hash = (hash * seed) + key.charAt(i);
}
return (int) (hash % capacity);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [wikipedia article on double hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing#Implementation_details_for_caching) suggests that you modify your hash function to avoid that it becomes zero, the easiest way to do that being to simply add `1`:

```
int h1 = hash_func1(s);
int h2 = (hash_func2(s) % (capacity - 1)) + 1;

// loop over (h1 + i * h2) % capacity
```

EDIT: Oops, I guess you also need to bound it by `capacity - 1`, otherwise with `h2 == capacity`, you would still run into an endless loop...
Or, even better, have `hash_func2()` already return a value less than `capacity - 1`, then adding `1` is sufficient.

Comment: This doesnt work for me. Can you show me a correct universal hash function for strings?

Comment: How does this not work for you?  Can you expand...  The logic applied accurately keeps the secondary value from being zero.  If you need both values to not be zero, simply apply the same logic again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using mzhash32 a very simple, fast function with a number of collisions very close to the Universal Hashing Function

```
public static int mzHash32(final byte[] data, int start, int length, int seed) {
    int hash = 0x95DE1432 ^ seed;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        hash = (0xA8657C5B * (i + data[start + i])) ^ (hash << 2) ^ (hash >>> 2);
    return hash;
}

public static int mzHash32(String str) {
    byte[] data = str.getBytes();
    return mzHash32(data, 0, data.length, 0);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/matteo65/mzHash32
64 bit version: https://github.com/matteo65/mzHash64